# How to send video to server from android,which able to play back in browser when go to the URL assign to it?

Tags: android, retrofit2, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I send a video file(capture from camera) to my PHP server using Retrofit 2,the video is successfully uploaded to a folder in server(I checked with FileZilla, the video exists in the folder),I assign the video to a URL,I go to the same Url(using browser) it cant play the video.

It just appears like this in Url(example: mydomain.cc/video/VID_2014.mp4)

[image]

So I test with a random video, send it via postman, the URL of that video is able to playback.

**Like so:**

[image]

My video file path in Android that I get in `onActivityResult` after capturing video looks like this

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ABC/VID_20171008_183129.mp4

**Here is my code for sending video file**

```
 private void uploadVideoToServer(String pathToVideoFile){
    File videoFile = new File(pathToVideoFile);
    RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SERVER_PATH)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    VideoInterface vInterface = retrofit.create(VideoInterface.class);
    Call<ResultObject>  serverCom = vInterface.uploadVideoToServer(vFile);
    serverCom.enqueue(new Callback<ResultObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResultObject> call, Response<ResultObject> response) {
            ResultObject result = response.body();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result.getSuccess())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Result " + result.getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Result " + result.getSuccess());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResultObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error message " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**VideoInterface.java**

```
public interface VideoInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("video.php")
    Call<ResultObject> uploadVideoToServer(@Part MultipartBody.Part video);
}
```

So my question is, why video capture from the Android camera not able to playback in Url? Does this matter?

Cause I worried later I need to display back to my app by using the Url, if matter how to solve this?

So somebody please give me a complete solution for doing this..

EDIT: 
I checked the codec by using the ffmpeg, here is the result..

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio and video codecs used by your videos matter; not all codecs are supported by all players. [Mozilla has a nice table of supported codecs by platform and player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). Based on this table, I think you want:

1. VP8 and Vorbis in WebM (requires container change)
2. H.264 and MP3 in MP4
3. H.264 and AAC in MP4

You can check the codecs using the popular [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) media player, or [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

After capturing your video, you may need to convert to suitable web codecs. ffmpeg is a free tool for converting codecs and containers.

The [ffmpeg documentation example for converting to webm](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

You may need to tweak the bitrate 1M for your quality/size preferences.

Comment: so means that the video's codec I record from Android,is not support in google chrome?

Comment: So I need to convert the codec of the video capture in android to which mention above?By using ffmpeg inside android??Am I right??

Comment: I don't know which audio and video codecs are being used in your capture file. If they are not supported in your browser, then you have to convert. This is one possible issue. You have to check the codecs in your captured file and see whether they are supported.

Comment: u mean checking it inside the android app??is this true??

Comment: No, I do not mean checking the codecs in the android app. You already have a captured video file. Use a preexisting application (vlc or ffmpeg) to see what codecs are used in this file.

Comment: I use ffmpeg to check the codec..what I  found is `Codec ID:mp42(isom/mp42)` is this means the video codec is `mp42`? so I need to convert this codec to `H.264`?

Comment: what I got in ffmpeg is `major_brand: mp4,minor_version :0,compatible_brands: isommp42`,so is it means that I need to convert it??

Comment: I added the result I got in ffmpeg,and mediaInfo,can briefly give me some idea what it means??

Comment: I suggest converting to the supported webm format with the vp8 and vorbis codecs. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Video MP4 store the metadata needed to play it at the and of the file. Did you wait for the complete download of video before give up ?

Comment: sir what you mean by that??cause I open the Url in browser quite a long time,but only seems like the 1st picture I post out..can u give me more info by this??

Comment: but the video is really exist in the folder in my server

Comment: I see the problem was the codec unsupported in browser. Anyway if you convert your video in MP4 H264/AAC with ffmpeg, keep in count what I said before. The output video MP4 has metadata at the and of the file so the browser cannot start to play the video as soon as get the first bytes (like Youtube does) , but it have to wait until receive all the file, then it can start to play